# How to clear textarea on WYSIHTML5

Tags: jquery, textarea, wysihtml5

```
<textarea class="textarea" id="actionplan" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
```

I am using ADMIN LTE's editor which is WYSIHTML5 and I want to clear the textarea after submission. I've tried using:

```
$("#actionplan").val("");
$("#actionplan").html("");
```

but it still doesn't work.

What are the other ways for clearing the wysihtml5 textarea?

Comment: will work: $('#actionplan').data("wysihtml5").editor.clear();

Comment: actually, I've tried using that already too but it still doesn't work.. @AbdulRafay

Comment: check: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sud00hs7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

just ..

```
$("#actionplan").val('');
```

but ... refresh cache javascript or never work !!!

you can refresh from code

```
< script src="../js/index.js?v0001"></script >
```

... before ...

```
< script src="../js/index.js?v0002"></script >
```

...